# Use the given information to write the formula of this compound

Tags: stoichiometry

the question says :

Two elements, A and B, combine to form two binary compounds. In the first
compound, 3.5 g of A combines with 8.00 g of B. In the second compound,
5.0 g of A combines with 17.1 g of B. If the formula of the first compound is
AB2, then the formula of the second compound would be ?

I can't even make the first step :(

Comment: As for your previous question, a question back to you to get you thinking: If the molecular formula AB2 gives a compound of 3.5g A, and 8.0g B, can you derive a simple A:B mass ratio ie for every 1g of A, how many grams of B?

Comment: by dividing ; 1g of A will give 2.29 g of B ?

Comment: No, this still represents a ratio of A:2B. You need to bring it back to give you a unity ratio A:B.

Comment: will it be 1g of A for each 4.57 g of B ?

Comment: Oops. Going the wrong way there. I hope you understand why we try to get you to do some working out before presenting answers to these types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a molecule AB2, 3.5g of A represents one molar fraction, and 8.00g B represents 2 molar fractions (or 4.0+4.0). Therefore, a direct ratio can be given as 3.5:4.0, or 1:1.14.  This means a molecule A<sub>n</sub>B<sub>m</sub> will give a mass ratio for A:B of n:1.14xm

For a molecule AB, for every 1g of A, you will have 1.14g of B.

For a molecule AB<sub>2</sub>, for every 1g of A, you will have 2.28g of B.

For a molecule A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>3</sub>, for every 1g of A, you will have (1.14x3/2) 1.71g of B.

etc etc

So for 5.0g of A, in order to have 17.1g of B, you will have 1.14 x (m/n) = 17.1/5

=> m/n = 17.1 / 5 / 1.14 = 3

This means m/n=3, or AB3 (alternatively it could also be A2B6)